# Macro in excel error when pasting

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I filter a column then I try to copy and paste the values.

However, I get the error PasteSpecial Method of Range Class Failed

```
Sub DD()
'
' DD Macro
'

'
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$132").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="1"
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$132").AutoFilter Field:=8
    Columns("I:I").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I6").Select
End Sub
Sub dds()
'
' dds Macro
'

'
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$132").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="1"
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$132").AutoFilter Field:=8
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("J9").Select
    Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("I6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The specific error is,

```
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
```

I am using the record macro function in excel. Any ideas?

Comment: Put Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False onto 1 line, the _ denotes a line feed, but it might be tripping itself up.

Comment: Alternatively try replacing Paste:=xlPasteValues with Paste:=xlValues

Comment: You could just do `Range("I:I").Value = Range("A:A").Value`, except that might take a while since you're copying an *entire column*.